# How to intersect two polygon-layers in PostgreSQL/PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, intersection

**EDIT:**

according to the instructions given by @raphael I created a new, smaller test-set. the old, obsolete original question is now at the bottom of this post

1) Imported two shapefiles into postgresql/postgis:

layer1 with 39 polygons

layer2 with 79 polygons

I used the pgadminIII plugin for the import of the shapefiles. Option is enabled for automatically generating a spatial index.

2) ran

```
analyze layer1;
analyze layer2;
```

3) ran

```
select *,ST_IsValidReason(geom)  from layer1
where ST_IsValid(geom) = false;
select *,ST_IsValidReason(geom)  from layer2
where ST_IsValid(geom) = false;
```

both layers are valid!

now I have 2 tables with spatialtype MultiPolygon in the database

see **screenshot2**:
layer1 = blue
layer2 = yellow
[image]
4) now ran

```
create table layer3 
as
SELECT layer1.id, layer1.bev, 
       ST_COLLECT(ST_INTERSECTION(layer1.geom, layer2.geom))
FROM layer1, layer2
WHERE ST_Intersects(layer1.geom, layer2.geom)
GROUP BY layer1.id,layer1.bev;
```

5) ran

```
select sum(bev) from layer1;
```

returns 56462

and

```
select sum(bev) from layer3;
```

also returns 56462

```
select count(*) from layer3;
```

returns 39

so all seems ok

but when I import layer3 into qgis I only have 27 polygons !!
(see **screenshot 3**)
[image]

6) ran

```
select *,ST_IsValidReason(st_collect)  from layer3
where ST_IsValid(st_collect) = false;
```

delivers no invalid rows !!!

and

```
select count(st_collect) from layer3;
```

delivers 39

*so what I am doing wrong?*

**edit2:**

the following seems to work:

```
create table layer4
as
SELECT layer1.id, layer1.bev, 
      st_union(ST_INTERSECTION(layer1.geom, layer2.geom))
FROM layer1, layer2
WHERE ST_Intersects(layer1.geom, layer2.geom)
GROUP BY layer1.id,layer1.bev;
```

**but I must confirm, that I dont really understand why  ..., a simple explanation for a mere mortal ??**

---

**old, now obsolete original question:**
I have 2 layers:

layer #1 named burgenlandzsp has 382 polygons (= red in screenshot)

layer #2 named siedlungsraum_singleparts_burgenland has 897 polygons (= green in screenshot)

**Problem:** I need to create a new layer which contains only the parts of layer#1 which intersect with layer #2.

I tried to do this in PostGIS with the following command:

```
create table bglsiedlungsraum as
select
   burgenlandzsp.id,burgenlandzsp.name,burgenlandzsp.zsp,
   burgenlandzsp.bev,
   ST_intersection(burgenlandzsp.geom,
                   siedlungsraum_singleparts_burgenland.geom) as geom 
from burgenlandzsp,siedlungsraum_singleparts_burgenland
where ST_intersects(burgenlandzsp.geom, 
                    siedlungsraum_singleparts_burgenland.geom);
```

I expected to get a new table(layer) with a multigeometry of 382 multipolygons, but it did not work

after about one hour this query "crashed" my hp-laptop (6mb ram, win10 64 bit, 4 cores @1,6 GHz)

[image]

Comment: im assuming your bringing this layer into QGIS? maybe try doing a select into statement instead of a create table as..that has worked for me before but I cannot tell you why

Comment: Could be a problem of geometry types. Could be that postgis delivers Multipolygons and Qgis assumes Polygon. The function ST_Dump will expand the Multipolygons to Polygons. Usage is: ST_Dump(actual geometry) as new_geometry

Comment: ok, trying to export via the pgadminIII plugin to a shapefile I get the error-message : incompatible mixed geometry types in the table. will look into the documentation for st_dump ...

Comment: I'd run `SELECT DISTINCT ST_GeometryType(st_collect) FROM layer_3;` to find out what you're actually dealing with.

Comment: @MichalZimmermann : layer1 are stastical districts with the number of people  in it. layer 2 are the "real" settlement areas . now I want that parts of layer1, where there are really people living

Comment: @Kurt that's not an answer to my question though :) You're using ST_Collect that might result in different types of geometries (even geometrycollections). Switching to ST_Union seems to be a good step.

Comment: @MichalZimmermann yeah, thats what I already did :-) see edit#2 and this also seems to be the reason, why qgis did not load all rows into the layer (see screenshot 3) , I just need to learn more about this strange stuff of spatial databases....

Comment: @Kurt go through the docs, the main difference between those two is that `ST_Collect` won't dissolve the feature boundaries while `ST_Union` will (or at least will give it a try and fail due to invalid input).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table layer4
as
SELECT layer1.id, layer1.bev, 
      st_union(ST_INTERSECTION(layer1.geom, layer2.geom))
FROM layer1, layer2
WHERE ST_Intersects(layer1.geom, layer2.geom)
GROUP BY layer1.id,layer1.bev;
```

quote from the [docs](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Union.html):
ST_Collect and ST_Union are often interchangeable. ST_Union is in general orders of magnitude slower than ST_Collect because it tries to dissolve boundaries and reorder geometries to ensure that a constructed Multi* doesn't have intersecting regions.

Answer (score 6):

> I expected to get a new table(layer) with a multigeometry of 382 multipolygons, but it did not work

Your expectation is incorrect. PostGIS is only returning ANY combination of layer_1 and layer_2 that [intersects](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html). If every polygon in `layer_2` straddled two polygons in `layer_1` the result of

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM layer_1, layer_2
WHERE ST_Intersects(layer_1.geom, layer_2.geom)
```

Would be 897 * 2.

If you want 382 multipolygons you need to use a combination of [ST_Collect](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Collect.html) with [GROUP BY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY) like so

```
SELECT layer_1.id, ST_COLLECT(ST_INTERSECTION(layer_1.geom, layer_2.geom))
FROM layer_1, layer_2
WHERE ST_Intersects(layer_1.geom, layer_2.geom)
GROUP BY layer_1.id
```

> after about one hour this query "crashed" my hp-laptop

Are you using a [spatial index](http://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#idm2198) on either layer? If not then PostGIS is doing 382 * 897 comparisons to check if each `layer_1` polygon intersects with each `layer_2` polygon, which may take a while.

Comment: so the shape-file-import plugin form pgadmin III  does not automatically create an index? using the link you thankfully provided, I can create a index : CREATE INDEX [indexname] ON [tablename] USING GIST ( [geometryfield] ); but how  do I tell postgis to use this index? how must I modify your example?

Comment: I think there's an option to create an index, but it's not enabled by default. You need to add the index to both tables, and then run `ANALYZE layer_1;` on each. Then PostGIS should just use the index automagically

Comment: ok, the option is enabled by default. I will run ANALYZE layername on each and proceed

Comment: according to your instructions I created a smaller test-suite, please see the edited question above. any hints??