# PostGIS intersect two polygons from geom tables PostgreSQL

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I want to intersect two polygons; they are in two tables stored in PostgreSQL. The names are "poligono" and "categorias_eot_paramo", respectively.

I am using the next simple syntax because I want to check the results where polígono intersect categorias_eot_paramo with the attributes from table categorias_eot_paramo.

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Intersection(poligono.geom, categorias_eot_paramo));
```

and then, I got the next error:

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "poligono"
LINE 1: SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Intersection(poligono.geom, categorias_e...
                                         ^
SQL state: 42P01
Character: 34
```

Comment: do your polygons really intersect each other? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/215949/276

Comment: You forgot to select `FROM` some_table in your statement.

Comment: We use a Question/Answer model here. Please do not edit the Question to contain an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message says, you must specify the involved tables in the `from` clause. You may also want to limit the result to the actual intersections, else it would also create empty intersections.

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Intersection(poligono.geom, categorias_eot_paramo.geom))
FROM poligono
 JOIN categorias_eot_paramo
  ON ST_INTERSECTS(poligono.geom, categorias_eot_paramo.geom);
```